# How many times was the owner of the bull that gores warned before punishment in Exodus 21:28-29?

Tags: exodus, law, moses

Exodus 21:28-29 NIV

> “If a bull gores a man or woman to death, the bull is to be stoned to death, and its meat must not be eaten. But the owner of the bull will not be held responsible. 29 If, however, the bull has had the habit of goring and the owner has been warned but has not kept it penned up and ***it kills a man or woman, the bull is to be stoned and its owner also is to be put to death***.

In the above texts there is no mention of the number of times that the owner of the bull should be cautioned prior to becoming liable.

Usually in such cases there was a specific time or number of days given before the capital judgement is carried out.

How many times was the owner warned before he became liable for the bulls actions?

Answer (score 4):

**Once, but once clearly**

That is, the ox owner has to have entered into the state of being warned. The word here is [Uwd](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/5749.htm), which means "warn" but whose etymology is about duplication. We see the word used in [Exodus 19:21](https://biblehub.com/exodus/19-21.htm) (so only a little before) with God speaking to Moses.

> (ESV) And the LORD said to Moses, “Go down and warn the people, lest
> they break through to the LORD to look and many of them perish.

How many time did Moses warn? Once. Thus there is nothing in the Uwd that would make us think it could not be once.

And our natural assumption should be that a verb mentioned without a number needs only be done once. Otherwise, how many times does the ox need to gore a person before being put to death?

The warning is not symbolic or legalistic, it is just. The punishment that comes from the owner's (presumed) ignorance ought to be different from when it is a known indifference.

The callous indifference that the warned owner must have for his ox to kill a person would rightly fetch a heavy prison sentence in our time; it rightly fetches death in the Bible.